# Can grazing lead to insulin resistence?

Tags: health, health-risk

For the last couple of years I've embraced the grazing food strategy, eating 5 small meals a day. Recently I've been reading a book (The Story of the Human Body) and have started to learn a bit more about how insulin resistance and type II diabetes work, and the thought came to me that a grazing eating pattern could potentially contribute to insulin resistance. The book didn't claim this, but it just occurred to me that a grazer will have more insulin spikes throughout the day than someone who eats 3 "square" meals. Googling didn't turn up much information as most of what I found is related to weight loss which isn't a concern for me. I primarily graze simply because I've noticed it causes my energy levels to be more consistent throughout the day. Anyway... any thoughts?